# register value different after printing x86_64 on unix,

Tags: unix, assembly, x86, x86-64

x86_64 On Unix

When I print %rdi 3 times the value is correct for the first print, then the second and third time printing the value is equal to each other but different from the first print ( set value )

Why is the value changing? how do I properly set/get/print the value from the %rdi register without this changing? also an example on how to pass %rdi to a function and maintaining the value on return would be Extremely helpful.

Looked extensively for solutions but i cant find any. Im building a compiler and my professor has given us close to zero documentation on x86_64, wouldn't tell me where to find proper documentation and I'm struggling to grasp what is happening here.

compile with gcc -o test test.s

```
    .section    .rodata
    .int_wformat: .string "%d\n"
    .int_rformat: .string "%d"
    .str_wformat: .string "%s"
    .nl_const: .string "\n"
    .initial_prompt_const: .string "\n\n\tAssembly X86 Test Program:\n----------------------------------------------------\n"
    .ext_const: .string "\n----------------------------------------------------\n\t\tProgram Complete\n\n"
    .sec_div_const: .string "\n------------------\n"
    /* Set and Scan */
    .calla_readb_const0: .string "\ta = 10\n\tEnter b = "
    /* Arithmetic prints */
    .aplusb_const0: .string "\ta + b = "
    .aminusb_const0: .string "\ta - b = "
    .atimesb_const0: .string "\ta * b = "
    .agtb_const0: .string "\tWrite(a>b) : "
    .agtb_const1: .string "\ta = 10\n\tb = "
    .comm _gp, 16, 4
    .text
    .globl main
    .type main,@function

main:   nop
    /* Push high address (saved registers) */
    pushq %rbp
    /* Set the top of the stack ( low address ) to the top of the stack (high address) */
    movq %rsp, %rbp
    movl  $.initial_prompt_const, %ebx

    movl $4, (%rdi)

    movl (%rdi), %esi
    movl $0, %eax
    movl $.int_wformat, %edi
    call printf

    movl (%rdi), %esi
    movl $0, %eax
    movl $.int_wformat, %edi
    call printf


    movl (%rdi), %esi
    movl $0, %eax
    movl $.int_wformat, %edi
    call printf
    /* Sets %rsp to %rbp, pops top of stack into %rbp */
    leave
    ret
```

Comment: `printf` is allowed to change `rdi` and a bunch of other registers. Read about the [calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI).

Comment: `movl $.int_wformat, %edi` will change `rdi`, as `edi` is lower 32b part of `rdi`, so it's not the `printf` first changing it. You need debugger anyway. Plus to study the ABI/calling convention into detail, unfortunately the x86_64 is like one grade more complex than old 16/32b, not so easy to be used by human. To store your `rdi` either use a register which has to be preserved (and preserve it first), or store the value somewhere. I'm not even sure what is correct way to work with stack in x86_64, simple push/pop around printf would probably break alignment, so rather sub rsp,<local_var_sz>.